# How to resolve Jenkins error when multiple POM files are deployed into the same place within Nexus Maven Repository?

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml, release, nexus

I have 3 different builds for SIT, UAT and Pre-prod in Jenkins. The following error message occurred when the 2nd build is uploading to Nexus Maven Repository.

Error Message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy- 
plugin:2.8.2:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: 
Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact 
com.companyabc.app.apigee:template-app:pom:1.0 from/to maven-releases 
Failed to transfer file: http://[REDACTED]/template-app-1.0.pom. Return code 
is: 400, ReasonPhrase: Repository does not allow updating assets: maven- 
releases.
```

This error message occurs after I have made 3 builds and is deploying the 2nd build to Nexus Repository (Release branch). I am guessing that the problem is because the deployment of first build uploads a POM file to the repository. The error happens during the 2nd upload of POM file as there is already an existing POM file in the repository.

Options I can think of:
a) Have different names for the 3 build's POM file
b) Hold out the first 2 POM files and only upload the last POM file.

If possible, how do I implement any of the 2 options in Jenkins. If not, what are other options to get around this problem?

Comment: You try to upload a non-snapshot version which goes in a different location than snapshots, and your Nexus does not allow that.

Comment: Releases are immutable which means you can't overwrite them...